# How to join two dataframes to create a data model to perform ETL operations in pyspark

Tags: join, pyspark

f

```
df_fact = df.select(
    "Player_Name", "Player_Height", "Player_Weight", "Country_id", 
    "Olympic_Year", "Event_Name", "Sport_Name", "Medal"
)

# Joining with dimension tables to get foreign keys
fact_table = df_fact.join(DIM_player, "Player_Name", "left") \
                    .join(DIM_sport, "Sport_Name", "left") \
                    .join(DIM_event, "Event_Name", "left") \
                    .join(DIM_Olympic, "Olympic_Year", "left") \
                    .join(DIM_Medal, "Medal", "left") \
                    .join(DIM_Country, "Country_id", "left")

# Calculate BMI (Body Mass Index)
fact_table = fact_table.withColumn("BMI", col("Player_Weight") / ((col("Player_Height") / 100) ** 2))

# Adding Player_Fact_ID
fact_table = fact_table.withColumn("Player_Fact_ID", monotonically_increasing_id() + 1)

fact_table.createOrReplaceTempView("FACT_Olympics")
FACT_Olympics_Table = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM FACT_Olympics")
FACT_Olympics_Table.show()
```

Need to create this Data model in picture with above code in pyspark[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6j8E.png)